# Read formula in the Google Sheets cells using Python

Tags: python, excel, api, google-sheets

I am trying to download a Google Sheets document as a Microsoft Excel document using Python. I have been able to accomplish this task using the Python module googleapiclient.

However, the Sheets document may contain some formulas which are not compatible with Microsoft Excel (https://www.dataeverywhere.com/article/27-incompatible-formulas-between-excel-and-google-sheets/).

When I use the application I created on any Google Sheets document that used any of these formulas anywhere, I get a bogus Microsoft Excel document as output.

I would like to read the cell values in the Google Sheets document before downloading it as a Microsoft Excel document, just to prevent any such errors from happening.

The code I have written thus far is attached below:

```
import sys
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
store = file.Storage("./credentials/credentials.json")
creds = store.get()

if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets("credentials/client_secret.json",
                                          SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build("drive", "v3", http = creds.authorize(Http()))

print("Usage:     tmp.py <name of the spreadsheet>")

FILENAME = sys.argv[1]
SRC_MIMETYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
DST_MIMETYPE = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

files = DRIVE.files().list(
    q = 'name="%s" and mimeType="%s"' % (FILENAME, SRC_MIMETYPE),
    orderBy = "modifiedTime desc,name").execute().get("files", [])

if files:
    fn = '%s.xlsx' % os.path.splitext(files[0]["name"].replace(" ", "_"))[0]
    print('Exporting "%s" as "%s"... ' % (files[0]['name'], fn), end = "")
    data = DRIVE.files().export(fileId=files[0]['id'], mimeType=DST_MIMETYPE).execute()
    if data:
        with open(fn, "wb") as f:
            f.write(data)
        print("Done")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Could not download file")
else:
    print("ERROR: File not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `gspread` library might be what you are looking for. https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Here's a code sample:

```
import tenacity
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

@tenacity.retry(wait=tenacity.wait_exponential()) # If you exceed the Google API quota, this waits to retry your request
def loadGoogleSheet(spreadsheet_name):        
    # use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API

    print("Connecting to Google API...")
        
    scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
        
    spreadsheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name)

    return spreadsheet

def readGoogleSheet(spreadsheet):

    sheet = spreadsheet.sheet1 # Might need to loop through sheets or whatever
    val = sheet.cell(1, 1).value # This just gets the value of the first cell. The docs I linked to above are pretty helpful on all the other stuff you can do

    return val

test_spreadsheet = loadGoogleSheet('Copy of TLO Summary - Template DO NOT EDIT')
test_output = readGoogleSheet(test_spreadsheet)
print(test_output)
```

Comment: I am sorry but I was not able to work out how I can use this library to do what I want to. Could you kindly share a code sample with me?

Comment: Oh gosh I'm sorry I haven't been on here in a month! You may have solved your problem another way by now but I added a code sample above. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python to export something from google docs, then the simplest way is to let googles own server do the job for you.

I was doing a little webscraping on google sheets, and I made this little program which will do the job for you. You just have to insert the id of the document you want to download.

I put in a temporary id, so anyone can try it out.

```py
import requests
ext = 'xlsx' #csv, ods, html, tsv and pdf can be used as well
key = '1yEoHh7WL1UNld-cxJh0ZsRmNwf-69uINim2dKrgzsLg'
url = f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/export?format={ext}'
res = requests.get(url)
with open(f'file.{ext}', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

That way conversion will most certainly always be correct, because this is the same a clicking the export button inside the browser version of google sheets.

If you are planning to work with the data inside python, then I recommend using csv format instead of xlsx, and then create the necessary formulas inside python.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not planning to work with the data inside the cells per se, I just want to port the document from Google Sheets to Microsoft Excel. I am checking for the cell values just so that I can earn the user about the fact that the Sheets document has fields that can not be converted to Microsoft Excel fields. If you know about any other way in which I can achieve this, kindly do let me know.

Comment: When I used the code you shared to download a document in the xlsx format, I received the error "We're sorry, we couldn't open your workbook. It's possibly corrupt or using a file format that's not supported." when trying to open it. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Ah ok maybe when you need to login to see the sheet then it will not allow you...

Comment: I guess you could either try unlocking the file for public, or someone can try to make a function which will log you in to google

Comment: Oh, okay. If the file I am working with can not be made public because of confidentiality issues, is there no other way? How can I log into Google? I have the credentials for Google Drive and Google Sheets API stored locally in JSON format.